# Bamboo trigger doesn't fire on fitered repository

Tags: git, include, repository, bamboo

I have a huge project located in git repository. It's a maven project that contains prenty of modules, most of them can be built and deployed separately, some of them are dependent of others. I configured git repository for buid plan and it works fine - once I pushed my changes, bamboo build is triggered.

But as I mentioned before, the project is huge and I'm searching for the way to optimize continuous delivery. I've tried to create a couple of build plans that only contain several maven modules. I created repositories for these build plans using "Include / exclude files" feature. I entered file pattern like /main-project/(subproject1|subproject2|subproject3)/* . The expressions work fine, bamboo picks up right subfolders when I run the build manually. The problem is, I'd like these plans to trigger automatically when something is pushed to the repo, just as it happens for the whole project with repository without include/exclude filters. But trigger doesn't work in this case. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Are you saying the trigger doesn't work, or the filter? I've just started trying to do a similar thing (a repo with 3 directories, a push triggers one of 3 Bamboo plans based on the directory) and it looks like the trigger fires but the filter is ignored.